# How can I remove extra whitespace from strings when parsing a csv file in Pandas?

Tags: python, parsing, pandas

I have the following file named 'data.csv':

```
    1997,Ford,E350
    1997, Ford , E350
    1997,Ford,E350,"Super, luxurious truck"
    1997,Ford,E350,"Super ""luxurious"" truck"
    1997,Ford,E350," Super luxurious truck "
    "1997",Ford,E350
    1997,Ford,E350
    2000,Mercury,Cougar
```

And I would like to parse it into a pandas DataFrame so that the DataFrame looks as follows:

```
       Year     Make   Model              Description
    0  1997     Ford    E350                     None
    1  1997     Ford    E350                     None
    2  1997     Ford    E350   Super, luxurious truck
    3  1997     Ford    E350  Super "luxurious" truck
    4  1997     Ford    E350    Super luxurious truck
    5  1997     Ford    E350                     None
    6  1997     Ford    E350                     None
    7  2000  Mercury  Cougar                     None
```

The best I could do was:

```
    pd.read_table("data.csv", sep=r',', names=["Year", "Make", "Model", "Description"])
```

Which gets me:

```
    Year     Make   Model              Description
 0  1997     Ford    E350                     None
 1  1997    Ford     E350                     None
 2  1997     Ford    E350   Super, luxurious truck
 3  1997     Ford    E350  Super "luxurious" truck
 4  1997     Ford    E350   Super luxurious truck 
 5  1997     Ford    E350                     None
 6  1997     Ford    E350                     None
 7  2000  Mercury  Cougar                     None
```

How can I get the DataFrame without those whitespaces?

Answer (score 62, accepted):

You could use converters:

```
import pandas as pd

def strip(text):
    try:
        return text.strip()
    except AttributeError:
        return text

def make_int(text):
    return int(text.strip('" '))

table = pd.read_table("data.csv", sep=r',',
                      names=["Year", "Make", "Model", "Description"],
                      converters = {'Description' : strip,
                                    'Model' : strip,
                                    'Make' : strip,
                                    'Year' : make_int})
print(table)
```

yields

```
   Year     Make   Model              Description
0  1997     Ford    E350                     None
1  1997     Ford    E350                     None
2  1997     Ford    E350   Super, luxurious truck
3  1997     Ford    E350  Super "luxurious" truck
4  1997     Ford    E350    Super luxurious truck
5  1997     Ford    E350                     None
6  1997     Ford    E350                     None
7  2000  Mercury  Cougar                     None
```

Answer (score 62):

Adding parameter `skipinitialspace=True` to [`read_table`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_table.html) worked for me.

So try:

```
pd.read_table("data.csv", 
              sep=r',', 
              names=["Year", "Make", "Model", "Description"], 
              skipinitialspace=True)
```

Same thing works in `pd.read_csv()`.

Comment: This helped me. I have values like " NaN" in the data and this makes it detect the NaNs no matter how man whitespaces there are in front of the "NaN" and without manually setting the "na_values" parameter.

Comment: While converters can do it and much more, for most use-cases, `skipinitialspace=True` is what folks want.  Should probably be the top answer!

Answer (score 31):

Well, the whitespace is in your data, so you can't read in the data without reading in the whitespace.  However, after you've read it in, you could strip out the whitespace by doing, e.g., `df["Make"] = df["Make"].map(str.strip)` (where `df` is your dataframe).

Comment: Super useful especially when outputting to a txt file where I did not need a header or index.This is the only solution that worked. `df["Make"] = df["Make"].map(str.strip)` then I applied `df.to_csv('no_head.txt',header=None,index=False)` and this eliminated the whitespace. Thanks again

Answer (score 15):

I don't believe Pandas supported this at the time this question was posted but the the most straight forward way to do this is by using regex in the `sep` parameter of `read_csv`. So something like the following should work for this issue.

```
table = pd.read_table("data.csv", sep=' *, *')
```

Comment: This works nicely, but in jupyter also requires the argument ```engine="python"``` or it dumps messy warnings ParserWarning: 
    Falling back to the 'python' engine because the 'c' engine does not support regex separators (separators > 1 char and different from '\s+' are interpreted as regex);

Answer (score 13):

I don't have enough reputation to leave a comment, but the answer above suggesting using the `map` function along with `strip` won't work if you have NaN values, since strip only works on chars and NaN are floats.

There is a built-in pandas function to do this, which I used:
`pd.core.strings.str_strip(df['Description'])`
 where `df` is your dataframe.  In my case I used it on a dataframe with ~1.2 million rows and it was very fast.

Comment: This answer aged well. "Doesn't have enough reputation". Has 595 at the moment and a gold badge

Answer (score 8):

[read_table](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_table.html) is **Deprecated**, Here is the message as it appears in the documentation.

> Deprecated since version 0.24.0.
>
> Use [pandas.read_csv()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html) instead, passing sep='\t' if necessary.

So using **read_csv** you can pass in a regex for the `sep` argument, where you can specify the separator as

```
sep="\s*,\s*"
```

**any number of spaces, followed by a separator, followed by any number of space again**, this will make sure all the leading and trailing spaces are also chosen as a delimiter chunk which in-turn removes the white-spaces on either side of your data.

regex details as follows:

```
\s -> white-space
* -> any number (zero or many)
, -> no meaning, direct character match
```

So, the regular expression `\s*,\s*` stands for `white-space[any number] match a comma and white-space[any number]`.

if your delimiter is anything else other than a comma then replace the `,` in the above expression with your delimiter. Eg: `\s*;\s*` if `;` is your delimiter.

Comment: If you have quoted strings in your CSV file that contain the separator character, this method won't work as it ignores the quotes. For example, rows like this: `1,10.2,"foo,bar",abc` will break due to that comma in between `foo` and `bar` being interpreted as a delimiter. 

I got the following error: `ParserError: Expected 31 fields in line 14, saw 32. Error could possibly be due to quotes being ignored when a multi-char delimiter is used.`

Comment: @Gabriel does just doing `read_csv` without the `sep` read the file into pandas dataFrame ?

Comment: yes, it will read the file but it won't strip the whitespace (which is the point of the OP). One of the other solutions posted here will be needed to do that.

Comment: @Gabriel it still can be done with regex but with much more complex expression.

Comment: I know, although I'm not proficient enough at regex to construct it! But the point is that the complex regex for my csv file might not work for another input. That's why I don't think this solution is as elegant as those that strip whitespace after the loading step.

Comment: yes stripping it later seems like better idea or if pandas provide it by default.

Answer (score 5):

Here's a function to iterate through each column and apply `pd.core.strings.str_strip`:

```
def df_strip(df):
  df = df.copy()
  for c in df.columns:
    if df[c].dtype == np.object:
      df[c] = pd.core.strings.str_strip(df[c])
    df = df.rename(columns={c:c.strip()})
  return df
```

Comment: Really handy  function to treat a dataframe.

Remember to return the object,
`df = df_strip(df)`

Answer (score 3):

The str.strip() function works really well on Series. Thus, I convert the dataframe column that contains the whitespaces into a Series, strip the whitespace using the str.strip() function and then replace the converted column back into the dataframe. Below is the example code.

```
import pandas as pd
data = pd.DataFrame({'values': ['   ABC   ', '   DEF', '  GHI  ']})
new = pd.Series([])
new = data['values'].str.strip()
data['values'] = new
```

Comment: Simpler is `data['values'] = data['values'].str.strip()`

Answer (score 1):

For me the best way was

```
def read_csv_regex(data, date_columns=[]):
    df = pd.read_csv(data, quotechar='"', parse_dates=date_columns)

    # remove front and ending blank spaces
    df = df.replace({"^\s*|\s*$":""}, regex=True) 

    # if there remained only empty string "", change to Nan
    df = df.replace({"":np.nan}) 
    return df
```

You don't need to write converter function and set it to every column, it works for head and tail spaces and has now problem with quotas unlike regexp sep.

See https://towardsdatascience.com/dealing-with-extra-white-spaces-while-reading-csv-in-pandas-67b0c2b71e6a#9281