# KeyError when selecting pandas columns

Tags: python, pandas, csv, keyerror

I'm trying to read in a CSV file into a pandas dataframe and select a column, but keep getting a key error.

The file reads in successfully and I can view the dataframe in an iPython notebook, but when I want to select a column any other than the first one, it throws a key error.

I am using this code:

```
import pandas as pd

transactions = pd.read_csv('transactions.csv',low_memory=False, delimiter=',', header=0, encoding='ascii')
transactions['quarter']
```

#### Traceback

```py
KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[10], line 2
      1 transactions = pd.read_csv('transactions.csv',low_memory=False, delimiter=',', header=0, encoding='ascii')
----> 2 transactions['quarter']

File ~\anaconda3\envs\py312\Lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py:3896, in DataFrame.__getitem__(self, key)
   3894 if self.columns.nlevels > 1:
   3895     return self._getitem_multilevel(key)
-> 3896 indexer = self.columns.get_loc(key)
   3897 if is_integer(indexer):
   3898     indexer = [indexer]

File ~\anaconda3\envs\py312\Lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexes\base.py:3797, in Index.get_loc(self, key)
   3792     if isinstance(casted_key, slice) or (
   3793         isinstance(casted_key, abc.Iterable)
   3794         and any(isinstance(x, slice) for x in casted_key)
   3795     ):
   3796         raise InvalidIndexError(key)
-> 3797     raise KeyError(key) from err
   3798 except TypeError:
   3799     # If we have a listlike key, _check_indexing_error will raise
   3800     #  InvalidIndexError. Otherwise we fall through and re-raise
   3801     #  the TypeError.
   3802     self._check_indexing_error(key)

KeyError: 'quarter'
```

#### `transactions.csv`

Full data [file](https://www.dropbox.com/s/81iwm4f2hsohsq3/transactions.csv?dl=0)

```
product_id, customer_id, store_id, promotion_id, month_of_year, quarter, the_year, store_sales, store_cost, unit_sales, fact_count
1,157,24,1869,12,'Q4',1997,'8.5500','2.9925','3.0000',1
1,456,15,0,6,'Q2',1997,'11.4000','4.3320','4.0000',1
1,638,11,0,9,'Q3',1997,'8.5500','2.9925','3.0000',1
1,916,7,0,4,'Q2',1997,'11.4000','4.9020','4.0000',1
1,923,15,0,7,'Q3',1997,'8.5500','2.7360','3.0000',1
1,1312,3,0,5,'Q2',1997,'8.5500','3.6765','3.0000',1
1,1565,24,0,9,'Q3',1997,'8.5500','4.1895','3.0000',1
1,2270,11,0,11,'Q4',1997,'8.5500','4.0185','3.0000',1
1,3065,3,0,11,'Q4',1997,'5.7000','2.5080','2.0000',1
1,3441,3,0,8,'Q3',1997,'8.5500','3.4200','3.0000',1
1,3528,17,0,10,'Q4',1997,'8.5500','3.8475','3.0000',1
1,4461,11,0,4,'Q2',1997,'8.5500','2.9925','3.0000',1
```

Comment: If, for some reason, the accepted answer doesn't work, or can't be used to parse out the leading and trailing spaces, then clean the column headers with `df.columns = df.columns.str.strip()` as shown in [Remove or replace spaces in column names](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41476181/7758804).

Answer (score 103, accepted):

Use `sep=r'\s*,\s*'` to parse a file where the columns may have some number of spaces preceding or following the delimiter (e.g.   `,` ):

```
transactions = pd.read_csv('transactions.csv', sep=r'\s*,\s*',
                           header=0, encoding='ascii', engine='python')
```

Prove:

```
print(transactions.columns)
```

Output:

```
Index(['product_id', 'customer_id', 'store_id', 'promotion_id', 'month_of_year', 'quarter', 'the_year', 'store_sales', 'store_cost', 'unit_sales', 'fact_count'], dtype='object')
```

Alternatively, remove unquoted spaces in the CSV file, and use your command (unchanged).

Answer (score 13):

I met the same problem that key errors occur when filtering the columns after reading from CSV.

###### Reason

The main reason of these problems is the **extra initial white spaces** in your CSV files. (found in your uploaded CSV file, e.g. `, customer_id, store_id, promotion_id, month_of_year,` )

###### Proof

To prove this, you could try `print(list(df.columns))` and the names of columns must be `['product_id', ' customer_id', ' store_id', ' promotion_id', ' month_of_year', ...]`.

###### Solution

The direct way to solve this is to add the parameter in `pd.read_csv()`, for example:

```py
pd.read_csv('transactions.csv', 
            sep = ',', 
            skipinitialspace = True)
```

Reference: https://stackoverflow.com/a/32704818/16268870

Answer (score 12):

if you need to select multiple columns from dataframe use 2 pairs of square brackets
eg.

```
df[["product_id","customer_id","store_id"]]
```

Comment: Don't know why all the upvotes, this does not resolve the `KeyError` issue in the OP: `df[["product_id","customer_id","store_id"]]` → `KeyError: "['customer_id', 'store_id'] not in index"`. Answers on SO, should answer the question in the OP, and selecting multiple columns is answer in [Selecting multiple columns in a Pandas dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11285613/7758804)

Answer (score 3):

The key error generally comes if the key doesn't match any of the dataframe column name 'exactly':

You could also try:

```
import csv
import pandas as pd
import re
    with open (filename, "r") as file:
        df = pd.read_csv(file, delimiter = ",")
        df.columns = ((df.columns.str).replace("^ ","")).str.replace(" $","")
        print(df.columns)
```

Answer (score -2):

Datsets when split by ',', create features with a space in the beginning. Removing the space using a regex might help.

For the time being I did this:

label_name = ' Label'

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Technically, this works, but it's not a good solution, especially in relation to the accepted answer. Data should always be cleaned, and this doesn't do that.