# Pandas KeyError for a column name when doing .groupby()

Tags: python, pandas

I know that this problem has been reported already, but I have been unable to resolve it for my dataset.

I am trying to read a .csv file in pandas and can access all of its columns using their names, except for one. I tried removing any spaces around the column names with the solution reported here: [Key error when selecting columns in pandas dataframe after read_csv](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35831496/key-error-when-selecting-columns-in-pandas-dataframe-after-read-csv/35831531)

The file reads very well, except when I try to access the column 'calender_date', where it throws a KeyError:

```
import pandas as pd

pd_bookstock= pd.read_csv('dataset_2019_01_24.csv')
pd_bookstock.groupby('calender_date')

KeyError: 'calender_date'
```

The dataset can be accessed from here: https://www.dropbox.com/s/h3361a36owuvker/dataset_2019_01_24.csv?dl=0

Thank you very much!

Comment: Print `pd_bookstock` and inspect actual column names

Comment: `print(pd_bookstock.columns)` and go from there

Comment: wpercy spotted it, not me, but its a typo between `calendar` and `calender`. It's a typo.

Comment: for some unknown reason, I no longer get KeyError when doing pd_bookstock['calender_date']. I get it when I do pd_bookstock.groupby('calender_date'). I don't get this error for other columns. Any ideas?

Comment: I have modified the above question accordingly

Comment: I noticed that pandas behaves strangely when it comes to KeyError. I solved the above problem when I printed all column names in a cell using pd_bookstock.columns, and then copy-pasting the column name from there into .groupby() code in the next cell.

Comment: You should change any ways the name of the column, because it says its `calendar_date` in the data you posted, as roganjosh marked

Comment: That's not acting strangely, that just means you didn't specify the column name properly. Unless there a bug, code is probably the closest we come to logic