# Pandas groupby column not found

Tags: python

I have code that looks like this:

```
import pandas as pd
df=pd.read_csv("averaged.txt",sep=",")
df.groupby("year")["tavg"].mean()
```

but I get this error:

File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/core/base.py", line 268, in **getitem**
    raise KeyError("Column not found: {key}".format(key=key))
KeyError: 'Column not found: tavg'

The first few lines of averaged.txt look like this:

```
year,tavg 
1941,2990.0
1942,2909.1666666666665
1943,-292.25
1944,2930.0
1945,2686.3636363636365
1946,2661.6666666666665
1947,2714.1666666666665
1948,2681.6666666666665
1949,2616.6666666666665
1950,2666.6666666666665
1951,2733.3333333333335
1952,2781.6666666666665
1953,2712.5
1954,2723.3333333333335
1955,2754.1666666666665
1956,2759.1666666666665
1957,2698.3333333333335
1958,2792.5
1959,2749.1666666666665
1960,2675.0
1961,2670.8333333333335
1962,2748.181818181818
1963,2676.6666666666665
```

Comment: You have an extra space avter column `tavg`

Comment: This question is a duplicate. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35831496/key-error-when-selecting-columns-in-pandas-dataframe-after-read-csv

Answer (score 1):

Your header seems to have an extra space right after `tavg`. Try:

```
import pandas as pd
df=pd.read_csv("averaged.txt")      # sep="," is set by default
df.groupby("year")["tavg "].mean()
```

In order to avoid this mistake in the future, you can simply clean your column names:

```
import pandas as pd
df=pd.read_csv("averaged.txt")   
df.columns = df.columns.map(lambda x: x.strip())
df.groupby("year")["tavg"].mean()
```

Comment: Oh my god. How could I do that? Thank you nonetheless!

Comment: I encourage you to accept the answer! even if it seems straightforward, having the error message and the solution next to it might help others.