# Exception has occurred: KeyError - 'Suburb' while using iloc within loop (Pandas)

Tags: python, pandas

I'm running into the KeyError only when I put the code into a loop. Running it outside of the loop works fine.

```
for filename in os.listdir(directory):
 df1 = pd.read_csv(directory+filename, encoding= 'unicode_escape')
 subname=df1["Suburb"].iloc[0]
```

I've removed all files but one in the directory (and confirmed that the spelling for the key is correct) and the error pops up.

Answer (score 0):

```
for filename in os.listdir(directory):
    try:
        df1 = pd.read_csv(directory+filename, encoding= 'unicode_escape')
        subname = df1["Suburb"][0]
    except KeyError:
        print(f'Latest file: {directory+filename}')
        print(f'List of columns: {df1.columns}')
        print(f'Is Suburb present as a column, True or False?: {'Suburb' in df1.columns}')
```

Comment: Thank you for the response.

I'm still getting the same error

Comment: Maybe the column Suburb does not exist or is incorrect spelling? Can you show screen shot of the data frame?

Comment: Hi Ian

Thanks for the response again. When I put the code outside of the loop it works perfectly. It's only when I add it to the loop it brings up the error. The dataframe prints correctly. I've also tried just changing it to the column number, and that produces the exact same error.

Comment: Can you try again. Try to see if any of the files have an issue with its column column name

Comment: No luck, unfortunately. I've even removed all files but two. Those two files have the columns copied and pasted. Nothing :O

Comment: Sorry I cant help. May try this 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35831496/key-error-when-selecting-columns-in-pandas-dataframe-after-read-csv