# Strip space from all column values in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I was working on a problem set where we have a lot of columns in a Pandas dataframe and many of these columns have trailing spaces. My question is, is there a better way to remove these spaces rather than creating a dynamic string (where we pass in column name as variable and append a `strip()` to it) and then executing it for every column.

Comment: Can you provide *any* sort of example input and output...?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Without an example it is not fully clear what you want to accomplish, but maybe the following will help:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'A  ': [1, 2], 'B ': [4, 5], 'C': [8,9]})
```

The column headers do have trailing white spaces:

```
df.columns
Index([u'A  ', u'B ', u'C'], dtype='object')
```

Now you can use `map` and `strip` to get rid of them:

```
df.columns = df.columns.map(lambda x: x.strip())
```

or alternatively

```
df.columns = df.columns.map(str.strip)
```

or simply (which should be the **preferred option**)

```
df.columns = df.columns.str.strip()
```

If you now call

```
df.columns
```

it yields

```
Index([u'A', u'B', u'C'], dtype='object')
```

If it is about the values and not the headers, you can also use `applymap`:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A': ['1', '2  '], 'B': ['4 ', '5 '], 'C': ['8 ','9']})

     A   B   C
0    1  4   8 
1  2    5    9
```

Then the following gets rid of the trailing white spaces:

```
df.applymap(lambda x: x.strip())
```

or alternatively (which is the **better option**):

```
df.applymap(str.strip)

   A  B  C
0  1  4  8
1  2  5  9
```

Note: This assumes, that you have only strings in your columns. You can also check [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13385860/how-can-i-remove-extra-whitespace-from-strings-when-parsing-a-csv-file-in-pandas).

Comment: yeah this is what I'm looking for, to get rid of white spaces from the values inside column, just one quick question is this approach scalable to large dataset for example table containing 100 columns and 100000 or rows?

Comment: Best thing is just to try it but I think it should work fine; also depends on your definition of scalable, of course. If the answer solves your issue, feel free to accept/upvote it :)

Comment: follow up question: instead of getting rid of all whitespaces in the dataframe, is there a way to replace them with something like '-' or '_' ?