# Dataframe failed to mask rows due to string values

Tags: python, pandas

I wanted to use column values in one csv file to mask rows in another csv,
as in:

```
df6 = pd.read_csv(‘py_all1a.csv’) # file with multiple columns
df7 = pd.read_csv(‘artexclude1.csv’) # file with multiple columns
#    
#  csv df6 col 1 has the same header and data type as col 8 in df7.   
#  I want to mask rows in df6 that have a matching col value to any
#  in df7. The data in each column is a text value (single word).
#   
mask = df6.iloc[:,1].isin(df7.iloc[:,8]) 

df6[~mask].to_csv(‘py_all1b.csv’, index=False) 
#
```

On that last line, I tried [mask] with the tilde, resulting in no change to the df6 file (py_all1b.csv), and without the tilde (producing the file with just the column headers).

An answer using a specific data set was provided in the below answer, but it did not work because there were inconsistencies between the text values, namely, on entry had a space while another did not.

The below answer is correct, and I have added a paragraph to show how the text issue can also be resolved.

Comment: Can you reduce this to a [mcve] please?

Comment: I would like to, but no I cannot.  As I stated in the answer comments below, the answer posted below is correct (I did check it manually and it did work when entered that way, so I will mark it correct. However, the solution (for some reason) did not actually fix the problem for the files I am using. I have no idea why.

Comment: I found the solution to my problem and posted an edit to the below answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try converting to a set first:

```
mask = df6.iloc[:,1].isin(set(df7.iloc[:,8]))
```

This ensures your comparison is against values.

**Example**

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame([[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9], [10, 11, 12]])
#     0   1   2
# 0   1   2   3
# 1   4   5   6
# 2   7   8   9
# 3  10  11  12

df2 = pd.DataFrame([[1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3]])
#    0  1  2
# 0  1  2  3
# 1  1  2  3
# 2  1  2  3
# 3  1  2  3

mask = df1.iloc[:,0].isin(set(df2.iloc[:,0]))

df1[mask]
#    0  1  2
# 0  1  2  3
```

**With strings**

It still works:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame([['a', 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9], [10, 11, 12]])
df2 = pd.DataFrame([['a', 2, 3], ['a', 2, 3], ['a', 2, 3], ['a', 2, 3]])

mask = df1.iloc[:,0].isin(set(df2.iloc[:,0]))

df1[mask]

#    0  1  2
# 0  a  2  3
```

When you are dealing with string data, there may be problems with whitespace that can cause matches to be missed.  As described in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13385860/how-can-i-remove-extra-whitespace-from-strings-when-parsing-a-csv-file-in-pandas/32589322#32589322), you may need to instead use:

```
df6 = pd.read_csv('py_all1a.csv', skipinitialspace=True) # file with multiple columns
df7 = pd.read_csv('artexclude1.csv', skipinitialspace=True) # file with multiple columns
mask = df6.iloc[:,1].isin(set(df7.iloc[:,8]))
df6[~mask].to_csv('py_all1b.csv', index=False)
```

Comment: Thanks, but that did not work either.  I manually checked the files to  verify it is not correctly masking.

Comment: My example has string values rather than integers. Might that be part of the issue?

Comment: @user3447273. No, strings should be fine. Feel free to change my example to see for yourself.

Comment: Your example does work, and one I did with a small set of values manually entered, also worked.  For some unknown reason, when I went back to my actual (larger) files, it did not work. The actual file has 40 different values to compare against a list with 550 values. After running it, some of the 40 (df7) were still found in the list of 550 (df6).

Comment: It does work. I've added an extra example. If you still believe it "doesn't work", please provide a **[mcve]**.