# Exclude rows that have empty cell

Tags: python, pandas, csv, numpy

I tried to exclude rows that have no 'UID'.
I tried

```
temp = pd.read_csv(link)
temp = temp[temp['UID'].notnull()]
```

It didn't work. I tried again,

```
temp = temp[temp['UID']!='null']
```

it didn't work either.

here's the output in a form of jupyter notebook.

[screenshot of the output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vq04c.png)

Comment: I suspect NaN isn't the same as null. And "nan" isn't the same as NaN

Comment: temp = temp[temp['UID']!='null'] is checking for string 'null'

Answer (score 1):

There is problem `nan` is string, so possible solution is:

```
temp = temp[temp['UID']!='nan']
```

Or:

```
temp = temp.replace('nan', np.nan)
temp = temp[temp['UID'].notnull()]
```

Similar:

```
temp = temp.dropna(subset=['UID'])
```

Answer (score 0):

You need:

```
temp = temp[temp['UID'].notna()]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `pd.notnull`

For example:

```
In:
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
d = {'col1': [1, 2,np.nan,8], 'col2': [np.nan, 4,7,11]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
df

Out:
    col1    col2
0   1.0 NaN
1   2.0 4.0
2   NaN 7.0
3   8.0 11.0

In:
df = df[pd.notnull(df['col1'])]
df

Out:
    col1    col2
0   1.0 NaN
1   2.0 4.0
3   8.0 11.0
```

Answer (score 0):

Try and resolve the issue when you *read* the CSV file. For example, it's likely that `"nan"` is surrounded by whitespace and therefore is not read in correctly as `NaN`. You may need to inspect the CSV file in a text editor to determine whether this is the case.

You can then deal with unexpected whitespace via `pd.read_csv`. For example:

```
import pandas as pd
from io import StringIO

x = StringIO("""UID,col2,col3
nan ,1,2
3,4,5
NaN,6,7""")

df = pd.read_csv(x, sep=' *, *', engine='python')

print(df)

   UID  col2  col3
0  NaN     1     2
1  3.0     4     5
2  NaN     6     7
```

`"nan"` is not read correctly as `NaN` without the `sep` parameter:

```
df1 = pd.read_csv(x)

print(df1)

    UID  col2  col3
0  nan      1     2
1     3     4     5
2   NaN     6     7
```

For more alternatives, see [How can I remove extra whitespace from strings when parsing a csv file in Pandas?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13385860/how-can-i-remove-extra-whitespace-from-strings-when-parsing-a-csv-file-in-pandas). Once the data is read is `NaN`, you can exclude relevant rows via `pd.Series.notnull`:

```
df = df[df['UID'].notnull()]
```

Answer (score 0):

pd dropna helps the best

```
df.dropna(subset=['optional_column_arg']]
```

[pd.dropna documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.dropna.html)