# How to trim Header values in pandas.read_csv

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm reading a csv file using `pandas.read_csv()`. My csv file has headers with spaces at start or end like `' header1', 'header2 '` I want to trim that extra space at start/end. Is their a way to specify this using some arguments? If not how to achieve that in my resultant dataframe?

Comment: You could try `df.columns =[col.strip() for col in df.columns]` after reading the csv.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try with this, after reading the csv:

```
df.columns =[col.strip() for col in df.columns]
```

Same as:

```
df.rename(columns=lambda x: x.strip(), inplace=True)
```

Or this too:

```
df.columns=df.columns.str.strip()
```

Comment: Thanks ! Which is Pythonic way among these two? :)

Comment: @MuhammadUmarFarooq I think the last one is the msot clear and idiomatic method.  Good answer.

Comment: I agree with Datanovice, I would use the last one @MuhammadUmarFarooq. Also, the list comprehension it's a good option and in most cases it could be the fastest way.

Comment: i would steer clear from method two, using `inplace=True` offers no real benefit and from what i remember may be depreicated in future pandas versions.

Comment: Yeah that's true @Datanovice.

Comment: @MuhammadUmarFarooq  actually, I just find another possible solution to your problem, they used regex for the separator; like `sep="\s*,\s*"`, but as you can see in the comments(of the answer), it could yield problems. Here is the answer: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55806282/13676202)

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/a/59242208/9375102 by cs95

Comment: BTW @MuhammadUmarFarooq, if you find the answer helpful, you may consider accepting it :)

Comment: Of course I'll accept. But give me some time, if anyone else want to answer my question.

Comment: Oh okay, no worries! :)