# pandas dataframe - remove all whitespace before loading df to_csv as a txt file

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have a df that I created from a mysql query. When I convert the query results to a df I see whitespaces between each column, but for the final txt file I need to make sure no rows have spaces:

This is what I've tried, if I do `sep = ' '` then it creates the space:

```
csv_data = df.to_csv(index=False)

s3.load_string(csv_data,
               key=test_file.txt,
               bucket_name=my_bucet,
               replace=True)
```

I noticed this question, but it looks like i would have to do `df["Make"] = df["Make"].map(str.strip)` for each column to remove whitespace

[How can I remove extra whitespace from strings when parsing a csv file in Pandas?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13385860/how-can-i-remove-extra-whitespace-from-strings-when-parsing-a-csv-file-in-pandas)

Example:
This is what is currently looks like with spaces, but I want to make sure all spaces are gone:
[image]

Comment: Please provide a reproducible sample of the CSV/input

Comment: An image is not reproducible, you must use **text**.

Comment: What do you mean by " I convert the query results to a df I see whitespaces between each column". The DataFrame is a Python class instance. It doesn't have anything "between" its columns.

Comment: @ThePhoton - the results from converting the df to_csv has whitespace between each value, I want to make sure there are no whitespaces between them

Answer (score 1):

### Quick Answer

I am not sure where the whitespaces in your strings are coming from, but no matter, here's a simple two line solution to your issue.

```
str_cols = df.columns[df.dtypes == 'object']
df[str_cols] = df[str_cols].apply(lambda x: x.str.strip())
```

Also, reiterating @mozway's point: much better to include text next time instead of images.

---

### Context

I forced a dataframe to contain whitespaces

```
df['Make'] = df['Make'] + " "
df['Model'] = df['Model'] + " "
df.to_csv("test_spaces.csv", index=False)
```

which produced a file looking like:

```
Year,Make,Model,Description
1997, Ford , E350 ,
1997, Ford  , E350 ,
1997, Ford , E350 ,"Super, luxurious truck"
1997, Ford , E350 ,"Super ""luxurious"" truck"
```

If I apply the above solution before calling `to_csv`, then I get the following output instead:

```
Year,Make,Model,Description
1997,Ford,E350,
1997,Ford,E350,
1997,Ford,E350,"Super, luxurious truck"
1997,Ford,E350,"Super ""luxurious"" truck"
1997,Ford,E350,Super luxurious truck
```